# Update not refreshing completely

Tags: bug, new-nav

When I first clicked on the 'favorite tags' option, I got the non-question page. Then when the update for my favorite tags happens, I clicked on the 'new activity' bar and got this result:

[image: Wierd Update Result]

Notice how the picture from the blank page, and the 'no results' language at the bottom are still there. Additional clicking doesn't fix anything, it just won't refresh.